# TaskScheduler that uses a dedicated thread

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, concurrency

I'm trying to implement a `TaskScheduler` that runs all tasks in the order they are submitted, on a single dedicated thread. Here's my implementation, using a `BlockingCollection`:

```
class SequentialScheduler : TaskScheduler, IDisposable {
    readonly BlockingCollection<Task> m_taskQueue = new BlockingCollection<Task>();
    readonly Thread m_thread;
    bool m_disposed;

    public SequentialScheduler() {
        m_thread = new Thread(Run);
        m_thread.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        m_disposed = true;
    }

    void Run() {
        while (!m_disposed) {
            var task = m_taskQueue.Take();
            Debug.Assert(TryExecuteTask(task));
        }
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks() {
        return m_taskQueue;
    }

    protected override void QueueTask(Task task) {
        m_taskQueue.Add(task);
    }

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued) {
        if (Thread.CurrentThread == m_thread) {
            return TryExecuteTask(task);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I've played with it a bit and it seems to work well. I have some lingering questions however:

- As you can tell by the Debug.Assert, I'm not sure how `TryExecuteTask` could return false and I'm just assuming that given my current implementation, it won't. Can that actually happen and what I should I do if it does?
- I'm not sure my implementation of `TryExecuteTaskInline` makes sense as it doesn't get called in my tests. If I understand correctly, this method should run the task synchronously if possible; hence why I'm checking if the current thread is the scheduler's dedicated thread.
- Also, my implementation of `Dispose` doesn't wait for the current task to complete, and will cause the rest of the tasks in the queue to just wait there forever, but short of making it blocking and wait for the queue to empty, I don't see how to do that any differently. I just need a way to release the thread.

Answer (score 7):

`TryExecuteTaskInline` is used in what is called "task inlining": basically, when you call `Wait()` on a `Task` that didn't start executing yet, it might be executed on the current thread. A simple way to test that is:

```
var factory = new TaskFactory(new SequentialScheduler());

factory.StartNew(
    () =>
    {
        factory.StartNew(() => { }).Wait();
    });
```

For more information, see [Stephen Toub's article *Task.Wait and “Inlining”*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-wait-and-inlining/).

But this all means that a `Task` might be executed outside of your `Run()` loop, so the call to `TryExecuteTask()` there might return `false`. Because of that, you should simply ignore the return value there ([just like the official example scheduler does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler), in its `NotifyThreadPoolOfPendingWork()`).

Another option would be to remove inlined `Task`s from the queue, but there is no simple way to do that for `BlockingCollection`.

---

I think that `m_disposed` should be `volatile`, otherwise, the `Run()` loop can be optimized into an infinite loop that checks the value of `m_disposed` only once, at the start.

---

For disposal, you might want to use [the completion capability of `BlockingQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086). That way, trying to schedule a new `Task` after the scheduler has been disposed will throw, which I think is the correct behavior.

If you do this, you can also rewrite `Run()` to use `GetConsumingEnumerable()`, and remove `m_disposed` altogether.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does this mean that my implementation of TryExecuteInline is correct?

Comment: I have difficulty seeing under what circumstances a task might be executed outside the Run() loop yet on the same thread, so perhaps my check there is unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

### Dispose the scheduler gracefully

As you mentioned, you lack proper disposal functionality.

> ```
> void Run() {
>     while (!m_disposed) {
>         var task = m_taskQueue.Take();
>         Debug.Assert(TryExecuteTask(task));
>     }
> }
> ```

The first issue is that `bool m_disposed` is not marked as *[volatile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile)*. This means that this variable is subject to optimisations that could render its usage invalid for your scenario. If optimized, the value will be cached once, and never re-read in the same ongoing method call, causing an infinite loop.

The second issue is that you can't abort waiting a new task using `Take()`. But there is a simple alternative `Take(CancellationToken ct)`; Keep track of a `CancellationTokenSource` in your task scheduler, pass its `Token` to `Take(token)`; on disposal of the instance, flag it by calling `Cancel()`.

I would also verify how `Debug.Assert(TryExecuteTask(task))` gets optimized in production code. And whether this could introduce unwanted side effects.

#### Revised

```
class SequentialScheduler : TaskScheduler, IDisposable {
    readonly BlockingCollection<Task> m_taskQueue = new BlockingCollection<Task>();
    readonly Thread m_thread;
    readonly CancellationTokenSource m_cancellation; // CR comment: field added
    volatile bool m_disposed;  // CR comment: volatile added

    public SequentialScheduler() {
        m_cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
        m_thread = new Thread(Run);
        m_thread.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        m_disposed = true;
        m_cancellation.Cancel(); // CR comment: cancellation added
    }

    void Run() {
        while (!m_disposed) {
            // CR comment: dispose gracefully
            try
            {
                var task = m_taskQueue.Take(m_cancellation.Token);
                // Debug.Assert(TryExecuteTask(task));
                TryExecuteTask(task); // CR comment: not sure about the Debug.Assert here
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            { 
                Debug.Assert(m_disposed);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks() {
        return m_taskQueue;
    }

    protected override void QueueTask(Task task) {
        m_taskQueue.Add(task);
    }

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued) {
        if (Thread.CurrentThread == m_thread) {
            return TryExecuteTask(task);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```